# How to add grid labels on the border of the data frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, layouts

> Licence: Advanced 
>   Version: ArcMap 10.1

I'm trying to place the labels of my measured grid at the border of my data frame. I've tried to edit the labels in the "Data Frame Properties -> Grids -> Properties" but nothing works. Only the border of the polygon will be labeled.

How can i fix that?

[image: left: wrong labels, right: labels which i want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Data Frame Properties it seems you have specified a clip option.
Go to Data Frame Properties and then to the Data Frame tab.
In the "Clip options" change from "Clip to shape" to "No clipping".
If you want to show only data that are within the polygon you might use the "Definition query" option in your shapefile properties.

Comment: You are right. I have specified a clip option in my data frame, and overlooked the activated Selection "Clip Grids and Graticules". Disabled it and now it works fine! Thank you.